# Не работает QTimer

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Имеется такой класс, слот `timerTick` не хочет срабатывать, в чем может быть дело?

```
class Example(Parent):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super().__init__(params)

        self.x = 0

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.win = uic.loadUi("tetris.ui")
        self.win.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

        timer = QTimer()
        timer.setSingleShot(False)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.timerTick)
        timer.start(100)

        self.drawMesh()

        self.win.show()

    def btnClicked(self):
        pass

    def timerTick(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1
        self.win.setWindowTitle(f"{self.x}")


if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = Example("")
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните ссылку на объект `QTimer`, иначе он после выхода из функции будет уничтожен.

Для этого сделайте переменную с ним как поле класса:

```
self.timer = QTimer()
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerTick)
self.timer.start(100)
```

---

**PS.**

У таймера `singleShot` по умолчанию `False`, поэтому `.setSingleShot(False)` не нужно писать